# Convert dataframe column to character vector

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataframe and I'd like to run a sentiment analysis on a particular column.
[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrrdV.png)

```
mysentiment <- get_nrc_sentiment(hud['review_body'])
```

However, when I run a sentiment analysis on R studio using the

```
get_nrc_sentiment function I get the error "Error in get_nrc_sentiment(hud["review_body"]) : 
  Data must be a character vector."
```

I tried converting the dataframe column to a vector using

```
as.vector(hud['review_body'])
```

The above doesn't seem to work as well. I've just started learning `R`.

Comment: conversion to character vector is `as.character()`.. Without `dput()` of your sample data, a more specific answer is not possible (for me)

Answer (score 0):

Sub-setting a `data.frame` this way: `hud['review_body']` merely creates a new `data.frame` with that one column. The result is still a `data.frame`, not a vector.

```
class(hud['review_body'])
## "data.frame"
```

You can extract the column as a vector in any of the following ways:

```
class(hud$review_body)
## "character"

class(hud[, 'review_body'])
## "character"

class(hud[['review_body']])
## "character"
```

Any of these will work with `get_nrc_sentiment(...)`.

The double square bracket notation confuses a lot of people. A `data.frame` is a list of vectors. Using single brackets extracts that element of the list, but it's still a list (with one element). To extract the contents of the element (the vector), you need to use double brackets.

```
x = list(A=1:3, B=4:6, C=7:9)
x          # list with 3 elements, "A", "B", and "C"
x["A"]     # list with one element (the "A" element)
x[["A"]]   # contents of the "A" element of the list
```

In future, please do not include pictures of data. Include the data.